# How to include backslash in include path?

Tags: php

I'm trying to concatenate multiple string in include path like this:

```
include dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '\application\language' 
    . '"\"' . SystemConfiguration::$language . '\language.php';
```

but I get this result:

> C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\MyApp\application\language"\"italiano\language.php

but should be:

> C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\MyApp\application\language\italiano\language.php

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to consider using `set_include_path()` - you could use it something like this:

```
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS .'application' . DS .'language' );
include "italiano\language.php";

/* or, more in keeping with the path */
include "italiano" . DS . "language.php";
```

Answer (score 3):

Jut use

```
. '\\' .
```

Instead of

```
. '"\"' .
```

backslash is for escaping to include one you need to add double backslash (\), and you are adding single quote and double quote both thats why "\" is adding in your path.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this syntax:

```
(...) '\application\language' . '\\' (...)
```

See more about [single quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Answer (score 0):

Use two backslashes. This is how you use literal backslash.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
include dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '\\application\\language' . '"\"' .
    SystemConfiguration::$language . '\language.php';
```

Character escape: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/2/6/2/escape-sequences

Answer (score 0):

```
include "C:\\path\\to\\file.php";
```

Note that PHP also accepts `/` to be used as directory separator on all systems, including Windows, so it is not a problem to use slashes always.